# How to solve non-linear equation iteratively (using Math.NET Numerics)

Tags: solver, nonlinear-functions, math.net

I have a specific **non-linear** equation of type:

```
a(1+cos(b))^2 = 4x * exp(-2c*(a-x)^2)
```

Can **Math.NET Numerics** solve this equation iteratively to get `x` when `a`,`b` and `c` are given?

The Documentation only talks about linear equations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember you can always put everything to the right hand side of this equation and find the root. Even if it's a bissection. It'll only take more time to solve.

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: @Saibot I used Math.Net Numerics. The method FindRoots.OfFunction() solves this issue without problems.

Comment: @selmaohneh Thanks. And is there a way to solve a system of non-linear equations?

Comment: That is the way to solve the nonlinear equation. Use the method to solve f(x)-nonlinearTerm=0

Answer (score 0):

It is about 6 years later, and I needed to solve a system of nonlinear equations with F#. I searched a lot to find a library, and even after all these years I still could not find a library for doing this in .Net.

I am leaving this comment in case others are in a similar situation.

I was able to create a library to emulate the ***fsolve*** function of SciPy and MATLAB. It can be called by F#, C# and VB

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HSG.Numerics

https://github.com/profhsgill/HSG.Numerics/tree/main

And for the above equation, for a = b = c = 1, the solution from my library function is =  0.7054892296501037